# Interpreting xhprof results - why yield negative values of MemUse?

Tags: memory, negative-number, xhprof

Why does it show negative number of MemUse?

[image: xhprof output]

Answer (score 5):

Functions can release more memory than they allocate. (Note: a function can release memory allocated else where.)

For example, consider a function `a()` which calls `b()`. Say, `b()` allocates a string or array and returns it to `a()` which then uses it locally and then `a()` completes. In this case, `b()`'s memory allocation will be `+ve`, whereas `a()`'s net memory allocation will be `-ve()` (because it was responsible for free'ing memory allocated in `b()`).

Comment: Hmm.. This certainly validates that we see negative memuse and that it is a valid case. Can you elaborate on what it means and how to traverse the compiled logs while profiling? Like, is this /bad/? Or maybe in addition to large memuse we should also then start looking for large negative memuse?